# VGG model not converging on CIFAR10 dataset using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

My code is available at

https://www.kaggle.com/aman0807/vgg-cifar10/execution

As you can see, the validation loss diverges from the start of the training.

I have tried with Adam optimizer as well as SGD optimizer. I cannot figure out what it is that I am doing incorrectly. Please point me in the right direction.

Edit: Included entire code here

```
# Importing Dependencies

import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import datetime

# Defining model
arch = [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M']

class VGGNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.conv_layers = self.create_conv_layers(arch)
        self.fcs = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=512*1*1, out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_layers(x)
        # print(x.shape)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.fcs(x)
        return x

    def create_conv_layers(self, arch):
        layers = []
        in_channels = self.in_channels
        
        for x in arch:            
            
            if type(x) == int:

                out_channels = x
                layers += [nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.BatchNorm2d(x), 
                        nn.ReLU(),
                        ]

                in_channels = x
            
            elif x =='M':
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))]

        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

# Hyperparameters and settings

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(device)
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 64
VAL_BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 50

train_data = CIFAR10(root=".", train=True, 
                    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), download=True)

# print(len(train_data))
val_data = CIFAR10(root=".", train=False,
                    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), download=True)
# print(len(val_data))


train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=VAL_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
# print(len(train_loader))
# print(len(val_loader))


num_train_batches = int(len(train_data)/TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE) 
num_val_batches = int(len(val_data)/VAL_BATCH_SIZE)

# Training and Val Loop

model = VGGNet(3, 10).to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
# optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, patience=10, verbose=True)

# save_path = os.path.join(r"trained_models", f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m%d_%H%M%S")}.pth')

def train_val():
    
    for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}/20")
        

        model.train()
        total_loss = 0
        for data in train_loader:
            image, target = data[0], data[1]
            image, target = image.to(device), target.to(device) 
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(image)
            loss = criterion(output, target) 
            total_loss += loss.item()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        print(f"Loss : {total_loss / num_train_batches}")
        
        save_path = os.path.join(r"trained_models", f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m%d_%H%M%S")}_{epoch}.pth')

        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)

        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()
            total_val_loss = 0
            for data in val_loader:
                image, target = data[0], data[1]
                image, target = image.to(device), target.to(device) 
                output = model(image)
                val_loss = criterion(output, target)
                total_val_loss += val_loss

            total_val_loss = total_val_loss/num_val_batches
            print(f"Val Loss: {total_val_loss}")

            scheduler.step(total_val_loss)
```

The output is :

```
> Epoch: 1/20 Loss : 1.3286100650795292 Val Loss: 1.3787670135498047
> Epoch: 2/20 Loss : 0.822020811685832 Val Loss: 0.948610246181488
> Epoch: 3/20 Loss : 0.6018326392113476 Val Loss: 0.9581698775291443
> Epoch: 4/20 Loss : 0.47134833609764004 Val Loss: 1.2446043491363525
> Epoch: 5/20 Loss : 0.35625831704114524 Val Loss: 0.8038020730018616
> Epoch: 6/20 Loss : 0.27602518926566605 Val Loss: 0.6090452075004578
> Epoch: 7/20 Loss : 0.21279048924686128 Val Loss: 0.6626076102256775
> Epoch: 8/20 Loss : 0.16782210255280214 Val Loss: 0.6386368870735168
> Epoch: 9/20 Loss : 0.12904227719518205 Val Loss: 0.8135524988174438
> Epoch: 10/20 Loss : 0.10961572862077902 Val Loss: 0.727300226688385
> Epoch: 11/20 Loss : 0.08377284912137456 Val Loss: 0.7346469163894653
> Epoch: 12/20 Loss : 0.07044737199237916 Val Loss: 0.8241418600082397
> Epoch: 13/20 Loss : 0.06040401630707726 Val Loss: 0.8411757349967957
> Epoch: 14/20 Loss : 0.05157513573171604 Val Loss: 0.9980310201644897
> Epoch: 15/20 Loss : 0.04703645325243019 Val Loss: 0.7441162467002869
> Epoch: 16/20 Loss : 0.039386494244257594 Val Loss: 0.7185537219047546
> Epoch: 17/20 Loss : 0.0361507039006692 Val Loss: 0.7251362800598145
> Epoch    17: reducing learning rate of group 0 to 1.0000e-03. Epoch:
> 18/20 Loss : 0.010131187833331622 Val Loss: 0.6911444067955017 Epoch:
> 19/20 Loss : 0.004273188020082817 Val Loss: 0.6758599877357483 Epoch:
> 20/20 Loss : 0.0023282255553611917 Val Loss: 0.6790934801101685 Epoch:
> 21/20 Loss : 0.002249847758697408 Val Loss: 0.6877240538597107 Epoch:
> 22/20 Loss : 0.0017385115527510854 Val Loss: 0.6955451369285583 Epoch:
> 23/20 Loss : 0.0015288436127294692 Val Loss: 0.6895047426223755 Epoch:
> 24/20 Loss : 0.0013521527944272392 Val Loss: 0.6986600160598755 Epoch:
> 25/20 Loss : 0.001302041847793007 Val Loss: 0.7062056660652161 Epoch:
> 26/20 Loss : 0.0009422088254753626 Val Loss: 0.721610426902771 Epoch:
> 27/20 Loss : 0.00092220353266205 Val Loss: 0.7185065150260925 Epoch:
> 28/20 Loss : 0.000855279816558849 Val Loss: 0.7262870669364929 Epoch  
> 28: reducing learning rate of group 0 to 1.0000e-04. Epoch: 29/20 Loss
> : 0.0009319903464029908 Val Loss: 0.7129291892051697 Epoch: 30/20 Loss
> : 0.0009213638452758586 Val Loss: 0.7219230532646179 Epoch: 31/20 Loss
> : 0.000790543920696094 Val Loss: 0.7180697321891785 Epoch: 32/20 Loss
> : 0.0007001494628562334 Val Loss: 0.7132201194763184 Epoch: 33/20 Loss
> : 0.000848956296528779 Val Loss: 0.720444917678833 Epoch: 34/20 Loss :
> 0.0007309111221651813 Val Loss: 0.7152464389801025 Epoch: 35/20 Loss : 0.0008760697004345624 Val Loss: 0.7213227152824402 Epoch: 36/20 Loss : 0.0007820251893755433 Val Loss: 0.7167501449584961 Epoch: 37/20 Loss : 0.0008780398232813891 Val Loss: 0.7176992297172546 Epoch: 38/20 Loss : 0.0006976223276931253 Val Loss: 0.7317324280738831 Epoch: 39/20 Loss : 0.0007082251550411605 Val Loss: 0.7190949320793152 Epoch    39: reducing learning rate of group 0 to 1.0000e-05. Epoch: 40/20 Loss :
> 0.0007200245124846 Val Loss: 0.7223398089408875 Epoch: 41/20 Loss : 0.0007270275670335591 Val Loss: 0.721064031124115 Epoch: 42/20 Loss : 0.0008191512905424633 Val Loss: 0.7175146341323853 Epoch: 43/20 Loss : 0.0007468872463225763 Val Loss: 0.7313894629478455 Epoch: 44/20 Loss : 0.0007858102934361841 Val Loss: 0.7234065532684326 Epoch: 45/20 Loss : 0.0008550570492202036 Val Loss: 0.7210699319839478 Epoch: 46/20 Loss : 0.0007921795028490795 Val Loss: 0.7209402322769165 Epoch: 47/20 Loss : 0.0007907233434224173 Val Loss: 0.7207257747650146 Epoch: 48/20 Loss : 0.0008106642895507929 Val Loss: 0.7174465656280518 Epoch: 49/20 Loss : 0.0008104693277185383 Val Loss: 0.7192382216453552 Epoch: 50/20 Loss : 0.0007664988370204754 Val Loss: 0.722599446773529 Epoch    50: reducing learning rate of group 0 to 1.0000e-06.
```

Comment: What was the accuracy of the model on test set? Would be better if you provide your code here not link.

Comment: Do you mean validation data or unseen test data? Also, I have included the code and output. Please take a look.

Comment: Solved it by adding a momentum of 0.9 in the optimizer. Posting in case anyone has similar issue in the future.